# odd result of snprintf format "%zu" between cc and c++

Tags: printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     char buf[100];
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "C %s %s %u %zu", "aaa","bbb",0,0);
     printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

cc -o test test.c

> > C aaa bbb 0 140733193388032

c++ -o test test.c

> > C aaa bbb 0 0

what's difference of two..?

### env

- Linux xxx 3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 16:05:25 UTC
  2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
- c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference, AFAICT. I wasn't able to reproduce, too. What are the versions of `cc` and `c++`?

Comment: cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Comment: uname -a
Linux xxx 3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 29 16:05:25 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20160623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong specifier - `%zu` should be used print print values of type `size_t`, but you are trying to print value of type `int`. Technically your program is malformed, its behavior is undefined.

Now, on what actually happens here and why do you see those results. You have to know following thing about [System V x86_64 ABI](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI):

- Type `int` is 4 bytes, while `size_t` is 8 bytes.
- Function parameters are passed through registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`, and further values are passed on the stack in reverse order.
- Parameters on stack should be aligned by 8 bytes.

And keep in mind that 140733193388032 is 0x7fff00000000 (lower 4 bytes are 0).

The code generated by compiler in your case is:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp], 0      ; <-- seventh arg passed on stack
mov     r9d, 0                  ; <-- sixth arg
mov     r8d, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0   ; <-- fifth arg
mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1   ; <-- fourth arg
mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2   ; <-- third arg
mov     esi, 100                ; <-- second arg
mov     rdi, rax                ; <-- first arg
mov     eax, 0
call    snprintf
```

Notice how last argument is written using 4-byte `mov` instruction. That means upper 4 bytes are not initialized and contain some garbage value. But because you are using `%zu` specified to print it, `snprintf` takes 8 bytes, printing zeroes in lower 4 bytes and garbage from upper 4 bytes. This also means such behavior can only be noticed for 7th and further arguments only.

Why is output of gcc and gc++ is different? Because different runtimes execute different code on startup. With C runtime it just randomly happen to have zeroes at upper bytes of this memory location, while C++ runtime stored some non-zero value there.

To avoid this kind of errors, compile you code with `-Wformat` parameter, or even with `-Wall -Wextra`. This will give you following warning:

```
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:7:47: warning: format ‘%zu’ expects argument of type ‘size_t’, but argument 7 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "C %s %s %u %zu", "aaa","bbb",0,0);
                                             ~~^
                                             %u
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. your answer is very helpful. Also i found that it's not snprint and %zu but 7th or more argument. i.e print and sprintf will occur too. And not only %zu but also %lu will occur too.

Comment: Yes, my answer explains why 7th argument is affected